# How can I add single character to the JTextField by pressing the JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

I am creating a simple program, which will allow me to add single character to **JTextField** by pressing **JButton**. In this program, I have an array of string named **words** & I have a String name **word**, which is allowing me to choose words randomly from the array of words. I am using a **for loop** to draw the **JTextFields**. Number of the JTextField depends on the length of the **word**

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.event.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.text.*;
    import java.util.Random;

    public class secondTab extends JFrame 
         {
             JTabbedPane Pane = new JTabbedPane();

             JPanel second = new JPanel();

             JButton guess1 = new JButton();

             Random r = new Random();

             JTextField Text[] = new JTextField[10];

             JButton A = new JButton();

             String words[] = {"JAVA" , "FLOAT" , "MAIN" , "STATIC", "FINAL", "PRIVATE" , "CHAR", "BOOLEAN" ,  "CASE"}; // An array to put the words

             String word = words[r.nextInt(words.length)];

             int i;

    public static void main(String args[]) 
        {
            //construct frame
            new secondTab().show();
        }

    public secondTab() 
        {
            // code to build the form
            setTitle("Adding Character");

            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);     
            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            // position tabbed pane
            GridBagConstraints gridConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
            gridConstraints.gridx = 1;
            gridConstraints.gridy = 1;
            Pane.setForeground(Color.YELLOW);
            Pane.setBackground(Color.MAGENTA);

            getContentPane().add(Pane, gridConstraints);
            getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());



            second.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            guess1.setText("New Word");
            gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
            gridConstraints.gridy = 0;
            second.add(guess1, gridConstraints);

            for( i = 1; i <=word.length(); i++)
                {
                    Text[i] = new JTextField();
                    Text[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
                    gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
                    gridConstraints.gridy = 2;
                    second.add(Text[i]);
                }  




            A.setText("A");
            A.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
            gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
            gridConstraints.gridy = 2;
            A.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            second.add(A, gridConstraints);
```

I have a JButton named **A**, this JButton is having some error. I have the string named **choice**, it contains only one character "Ä". So, I added some method in my Jbutton, Which compare the string **choice** to the **word** *( the word which is randomly selected above).* Whenever it find "A" in the **word**, it must have to  draw that "A" in the Jtextfield to the specific location but its not drawing...

```
            A.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {               
                              String choice = "A";

                              if (i < word.length() & i < choice.length())
                                {
                                    if (word.charAt(i) == choice.charAt(i))
                                        {
                                           Text[i].setText(choice.charAt(i) + " ");
                                        }
                                }  
                        }
                });

            // Action Performed method for the JButton guess1
            guess1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
                {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                        {
                            dispose();
                            new secondTab().show();
                        }
                });


            Pane.addTab("Game ", second); 

            pack();
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            setBounds((int) (0.5 * (screenSize.width - getWidth())), (int) (0.5 * 
                    (screenSize.height - getHeight())), getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

    }
```

Please check that video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tx5QsET9IWs starting from 0.41 second . I wanna do the same thing...

Thanks....

Comment: I think you actionPerfomed method's logic is wrong...

Comment: that could be possible, because I really don know how to do it.. I checked some program and understands them, then I did it..

Comment: 1. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 2. A single blank line of white space is always enough.   3. Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the use of the `i` variable

It is first used to construct the fields

```
for( i = 1; i <=word.length(); i++)
{
    Text[i] = new JTextField();
    Text[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 80));
    gridConstraints.gridx = 0;
    gridConstraints.gridy = 2;
    second.add(Text[i]);
}
```

This now means that `i` is now equal to `word.length()`

You then re-use the variable (as is)...

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{               
    String choice = "A";

    if (i < word.length() & i < choice.length())
    {
        if (word.charAt(i) == choice.charAt(i))
        {
            Text[i].setText(choice.charAt(i) + " ");
        }
    }  
}
```

Which won't work.  `i` equals `word.length()`, meaning it will never enter the first level of the `if` statement.

Make `i` local and use it only to build the field array.

In the `actionPerformed` method, you simply need to be checking all the occurrences of `A` within the word and set the appropriate text field

### Updated with working example...

There are a number of tricks for trying to find the index of all the occurrences of character in the `String`.

The simplest would be to simply loop through the length of the `String` and use `String#charAt` and compare that with the value you are trying to match...

```
for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
    if (Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(index)) == Character.toLowerCase(choice)) {
        Text[index].setText(Character.toString(choice));
    }
}
```

I use a slightly more complicated, but flexible approach, using regular expression to find all the occurrence of a given pattern...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import static javax.swing.Action.NAME;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class WordGuess {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WordGuess();
    }

    public WordGuess() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public static final String WORDS[] = {"JAVA", "FLOAT", "MAIN", "STATIC", "FINAL", "PRIVATE", "CHAR", "BOOLEAN", "CASE"}; // An array to put the words
        private String word;
        private List<JTextField> fields;
        private JPanel pnlFields;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            pnlFields = new JPanel();
            add(pnlFields);

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < 26; index++) {
                if (index % 13 == 0) {
                    gbc.gridx = 0;
                    gbc.gridy++;
                }
                gbc.gridx++;
                JButton btn = new JButton(new LetterAction(Character.toString((char) ('A' + index))));
                btn.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
                buttons.add(btn, gbc);
            }

            add(buttons, BorderLayout.NORTH);

            reset();
        }

        public void reset() {

            word = WORDS[(int) Math.round(Math.random() * (WORDS.length - 1))];
            pnlFields.removeAll();
            fields = new ArrayList<>(word.length());
            for (int index = 0; index < word.length(); index++) {
                JTextField field = new JTextField(3);
                field.setEditable(false);
                field.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
                pnlFields.add(field);
                fields.add(field);
            }

        }

        protected class LetterAction extends AbstractAction {

            public LetterAction(String value) {
                putValue(NAME, value);
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String value = getValue(NAME).toString().toLowerCase();
                List<Integer[]> occurances = findAllIndicies(word.toLowerCase(), value);
                System.out.println(word + " has " + occurances.size() + " occurances of " + value);
                for (Integer[] index : occurances) {
                    fields.get(index[0]).setText(value.toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static List<Integer[]> findAllIndicies(String value, String regExp) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regExp);
        return findAllIndicies(value, pattern);
    }

    public static List<Integer[]> findAllIndicies(String value, Pattern pattern) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
        String match = null;
        List<Integer[]> lstMatches = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(5);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            int startIndex = matcher.start();
            int endIndex = matcher.end();
            lstMatches.add(new Integer[]{startIndex, endIndex});
        }

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(lstMatches);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can check the occurrences, but then how can I set the appropriate text field, this part is confusing

Comment: I know its useful, but its way to complicated... :(. My level is not that high yet...!!

Comment: Time to stretch. The look up doesn't need to use the regular expression, you could replace it with the loop I first suggested