# Reading text from a file onto a JTextField array

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextfield, bufferedreader

I've been working on a wheel of fortune game for a school project for a while now, and ran into a problem with reading text from files that act as the puzzles onto a `JTextField array` which acts as the board where the puzzle is displayed.

What I have so far: A GUI for the game to run, as well as all the graphical components that will be included. This is the code for creating the puzzle board within the class `letterBoard`

```
import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import javax.swing.*;

 public class letterBoard extends JPanel
                            implements ActionListener                   
 {
 private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[TEXT_FIELD_COUNT];
 private Box[] boxes = new Box[SUIT_COUNT];
 private static int TEXT_FIELD_COUNT = 14;
 private static int SUIT_COUNT = 1;
 Color yungMoney = new Color(0, 180, 100);
 static String[] fieldsArray = new String[52];


public letterBoard()
{
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1,299));
    setBackground(yungMoney);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,14));
    panel.setBackground(yungMoney);
    for(int t=0; t<4; t++)
    {
        for (int i =0; i < boxes.length; i++)
        {
            boxes[i] = Box.createHorizontalBox();
            for (int j=0; j< TEXT_FIELD_COUNT/SUIT_COUNT; j++)
            {
                int index = i * (TEXT_FIELD_COUNT/SUIT_COUNT) + j;
                fields[index] = new JTextField("    ");
                fields[index].setEditable(false);
                fields[index].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 50));
                fields[index].setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,1));
                panel.add(fields[index]);
            }
        }
    }
    panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,2),"WHEEL OF FORTUNE"));
    add(panel);
}
```

This board is where the puzzle will be displayed. I have a `JButton` `reset` whithin the `wheelGUI` class, which acts as the main class for the program that all other classes run through.

What I want to happen: Upon a user clicking the `JButton reset`, the program should read a line from a text file which will act as the puzzle for this round. It should put one character in each box of the board, and leave spaces blank. It should turn any box with a letter occupying it black, to signify that a letter that has yet to be guessed is positioned there.

What's not working: A `FileInputStream` and `BufferedReader` don't seem to be compatible with `swing` components such as a `JTextField[]`. I'm not sure of another way to read a file into a `JTextField[]`, or if it's even possible with the way the board is created. Thank you!

Note: Here is the code for the `wheelGUI` class. The other code in there is related to separate classes.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class wheelGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private playerPlate player1, player2, player3;
Color yungMoney = new Color(0, 180, 100);
private String fileName = "D:/Users/Garrett/Workspace/WheelOfFortune/src/wheelOfFortune/img/wheel1.png";
private String cat;
private static String spinValue;
private String[] wheelStuff = new String[]{"Bankrupt", "Lose a Turn", "$5000", "$600", "$500", "$300", "$800", "$550", "$400", "$900", "$350", "$450", "$700"};
private JTextField results;
private static JButton spin, solve, buyVowel, guess, reset, end, cont;
private int numVowel;
private int numLetter;
private static int currentPlayer;
public wheelGUI() {
    super("Butt Stuff!");

    ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(fileName);
    JLabel picture = new JLabel(i);

    player1 = new playerPlate("Garrett", Color.RED, 0);
    player2 = new playerPlate("Jonny", Color.YELLOW, 1);
    player3 = new playerPlate("Robert", Color.BLUE, 2);

    letterBoard letters = new letterBoard();
    catBox category = new catBox(cat);
    inputField input = new inputField();

    Box wall = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    wall.add(player1);
    wall.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
    wall.add(player2);
    wall.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
    wall.add(player3);

    spin = new JButton("Spin!");
    spin.addActionListener(this);
    solve = new JButton("Solve the Puzzle");
    solve.addActionListener(this);
    buyVowel = new JButton("Buy a Vowel");
    buyVowel.addActionListener(this);
    guess = new JButton("Guess a Letter");
    guess.addActionListener(this);
    reset = new JButton("Reset");
    reset.addActionListener(this);
    cont = new JButton("Continue");
    cont.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));
    buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,380));
    buttonPanel.setBackground(yungMoney);
    buttonPanel.add(spin);
    buttonPanel.add(guess);
    buttonPanel.add(buyVowel);
    buttonPanel.add(solve);
    buttonPanel.add(cont);
    buttonPanel.add(reset);

    JPanel result = new JPanel();
    result.setBackground(yungMoney);
    results = new JTextField(spinValue);
    results.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    results.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    results.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK,2));
    results.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,100));
    results.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 28));
    results.setEditable(false);
    result.add(results);

    Box catInput = Box.createVerticalBox();
    catInput.add(category);
    catInput.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(50));
    catInput.add(result);
    catInput.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(100));
    catInput.add(input);

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(yungMoney);
    c.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    c.add(wall, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    c.add(letters, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    c.add(picture, BorderLayout.WEST);
    c.add(catInput, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
public JTextField spinWheel(String[] wheelStuff)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    spinValue = wheelStuff[rnd.nextInt(wheelStuff.length)];
    results.setText(spinValue);
    return results;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{
    JButton b = (JButton)e.getSource();
    if(b==spin)
    {
        spinWheel(wheelStuff);
        repaint();
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    wheelGUI window = new wheelGUI();
    window.setBounds(50, 50, 1024, 768);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Also, it doesn't really matter to me what class the method to make the puzzle is in. I'd assume putting it in the `letterBoard` class would be the easiest. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to read a line of the file, read the entire file into something like a `java.util.List`.

When the user clicks "reset", simply select the next element from the list and use a loop to get each character from the `String`.

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745636/how-can-i-add-single-character-to-the-jtextfield-by-pressing-the-jbutton/16745795#16745795) which demonstrates the basic concept of building the text fields using a `String` which is broken down into it's individual characters